# How to use environment variables defined in helm chart in Python

Tags: python, kubernetes, azure-devops, kubernetes-helm, helm3

My Deployment.yaml looks like

```
env:
- name: PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
   configMapKeyRef:
       name: svc-properties
       key: PASSWORD
```

How can i use the Password variable in python code now? Is it like os.getenv("PASSWORD") ??

Comment: It is exactly `os.getenv("PASSWORD")`

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
home_dir = os.environ['PASSWORD']
```